# how to generate dynamic Json in Spring boot

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, rest

I write a API Restful services. But JSON has to change now. I have to remove some fields in output JSON in output.

my JSON is:

```
{
    "id": "10001",
    "name": "math",
    "family": "mac",
    "code": "1",
    "subNotes": [
        {
            "id": null,
            "name": "john",
            "family": null,
            "code": "1-1",
            "subNotes": null
        },
        {
            "id": null,
            "name": "cris",
            "family": null,
            "code": "1-2",
            "subNotes": null
        },
        {
            "id": null,
            "name": "eli",
            "family": null,
            "code": "1-3",
            "subNotes": null
        },
    ]
},
```

But, the requirement is something like this:

```
{
    "id": "10001",
    "name": "math",
    "family": "mac",
    "code": "1",
    "subNotes": [
        {
            "name": "john",
            "code": "1-1",
        },
        {
            "name": "cris",
            "code": "1-2",
        },
        {
            "name": "eli",
            "code": "1-3",
        },
    ]
},
```

can I change it without create 2 Object (parent, child) ?
what's better solution ?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Do you already have the DTOs that are serialized as JSON? Can you change them? Can you add annotations on some fields/properties to ignore them when generating the JSON? Which part exactly is "dynamic"? Are you asking if a `Map<String, Object>` can be serialized to JSON?

Comment: can you share the code for creating the json output you've shown in the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ignore null fields at the class level by using `@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)` to only include non-null fields, thus excluding any attribute whose value is null.

```
@Data
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class testDto {

     private String id;
     private String name;
     private String family;
     private String code;
     private List<testDto> subNotes;
}
```

and then my result:

```
{
  "id": "10001",
  "name": "math",
  "family": "mac",
  "code": "1",
  "subNotes": [
    {
      "name": "john",
      "code": "1-1"
    },
    {
      "name": "cris",
      "code": "1-2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Documentation: [3 ways to ignore null fields while converting Java object to JSON using Jackson](https://www.java67.com/2019/09/3-ways-to-ignore-null-fields-in-json-java-jackson.html#:%7E:text=You%20can%20ignore%20null%20fields%20at%20the%20class%20level%20by,to%20json%20if%20it%27s%20null.)

Answer (score 0):

I used jackson annotation, it's working .

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude.Include;

public class TestDto implements Serializable {

    @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
    private String id;

    @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
    private String name;
    
    @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
    private String family;
    
    @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
    private String code;
    
    @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
    private List<TestDto> subNotes;
    
    //getter and setter ...
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 way you can refactor the same Object without creating another for your purpose

1. @JsonIgnore at **properties you don't want to be included**
2. @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL) when your field is always null and you do not want that
3. @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY) when you do not want to include empty list

Point 2, 3 is alredy shared in answer so for first option

```
public class testDto {
 @JsonIgnore
 private String id;
 private String name;
 @JsonIgnore
 private String family;
 private String code;
 @JsonIgnore
 private List<testDto> subNotes;
```

}